# Android Studio. AddRule Null pointer Exception

Tags: android, loops, android-studio, nullpointerexception

I've got a problem with the addRule function in Android Studio.
I loop trough an Array list of Languages.
For every language I add a Textview. After I added 1 textview, the next Textview should be aligned under the first one. I get a NullpointerException at the addrule line. Is my way of setting and getting the Id of the view wrong? Sorry for incomplete Xml. The whole Xml code is inside a Relative Layout.

```
private void listLanguages() {

    RelativeLayout relativelayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.addrole);
    int e;
    for (int i=0; i < languages.size(); i++) {
        TextView textview = new TextView(AddRole.this);
        if (i > 0) {
        e = i-1;
            RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) textview.getLayoutParams();
            lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,e);
            textview.setLayoutParams(lp);
        }
        textview.setText(languages.get(i));
        textview.setId(i);
        relativelayout.addView(textview);

}
```

XML:

```
<include
    layout = "@layout/esnmis"
    android:id="@+id/esnmis"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="55dp">
</include>

<TextView
    android:layout_width="250dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:inputType="textPersonName"
    android:layout_below="@+id/esnmis"
    android:textSize="30dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:id="@+id/description"
    android:layout_marginTop="4dp"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_below="@id/description"
    android:id="@+id/addrole">

</RelativeLayout>

<Button
    android:text=""
    android:textSize="20dp"
    android:textAllCaps="false"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/insert"
    android:layout_below="@+id/addrole"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:layout_marginTop="5dp" />
```

Error:

> E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                     Process: com.example.obo.database, PID: 11262
>                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to read from field 'int android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.width' on a null object reference
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams.(ViewGroup.java:7346)
>                         at android.view.ViewGroup$MarginLayoutParams.(ViewGroup.java:7643)
>                         at android.widget.RelativeLayout$LayoutParams.(RelativeLayout.java:1345)
>                         at com.example.obo.database.AddRole.listLanguages(AddRole.java:107)
>                         at com.example.obo.database.AddRole.access$300(AddRole.java:28)
>                         at com.example.obo.database.AddRole$1$1.run(AddRole.java:79)
>                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
>                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:7331)
>                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1230)
>                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1120)

Comment: Are you sure that `AddRole.java:107` is this line `lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,e);`? If so I guess that `lp` is nothing. Can you confirm? Put a breakpoint on this line and look at `textview.getLayoutParams()`. I guess this is a null object.

Comment: You created the TextView programmatically so you have to create also the LayoutParameters and add them to your TextView.

Comment: As shadowsheep mentions, you'll have to create the `LayoutParams`, too. `View`s don't automatically have `LayoutParams`. Also, you'll have to start your IDs at at least 1. If you try to create a relative rule with a sibling whose ID is 0, it will be ignored.

Comment: Thank you very much. This information helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to shadowsheep and Mike M. my app works fine aggain. Here is a solution for other guys with the same problem:

private void listLanguages() {

```
RelativeLayout relativelayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.addrole);
int e;
for (int i=1; i < languages.size() + 1; i++) {
    TextView textview = new TextView(AddRole.this);
    if (i > 1) {
    e = i-1;
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        lp.addRule(RelativeLayout.BELOW,e);
        textview.setLayoutParams(lp);
    }
    textview.setText(languages.get(i - 1));
    textview.setId(i);
    relativelayout.addView(textview);
```

}